# Encrypt user email address

Tags: asp.net-mvc, email, encryption, identity

In an out of the box ASP.Net MVC 5 web application using local SQL authentication, the user password is encrypted in Identity. Is it possible to encrypt the user's email address as well without creating an entirely new UserStore?

I understand how to encrypt the address, but haven't had much luck beyond that.

Thanks!

Comment: The password is not encrypted. Its hashed. Why would you want to encrypt an email address?

Comment: @Stephen - Yes... hashed, thanks. We want any "sensitive" data encrypted and the user email has been deemed sensitive.

Comment: Password hashing is an intentionally irreversible process. It is one-way to allow for comparison of the password provided by the user during login against the securely hashed stored value in the database. To encrypt the email address, use a standard AES encryption (with a mode of operation better than ECB) and intercept on storage/retrieval and perform the respective encrypt/decrypt operation as you would on any other piece of data. You'll also have to perform key management activities to handle this.